# DTDL - How to create object for location (lat,long)?

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I have DTDL model similar to below. I can use Json as string and store lat,long values. But,

**How I can store lat,long array of locations using objects.**

```
{
  "@id": "dtmi:DigitalTwins:BasicInfra;2",
  "@type": "Interface",
  "displayName": "BasicInfra interface model",
  "@context": "dtmi:dtdl:context;2",
  "contents": [
    {
      "@type": "Property",
      "name": "name",
      "schema": "string"
    },
    {
       "@type": "Property",
       "name": "location",
      "description": "Polygon/PolyLine Format Location",
       "schema": {
          "@type": "Object",
          "fields": [
                     {
                      "name": "x",
                      "schema": "double"
                     },
                     {
                      "name": "y",
                      "schema": "double"
                     }
                    ]
        }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Relationship",
      "name": "contains"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Related Q&A thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/142414/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this question.

We got a response from Microsoft's Product Team.

> **At the moment, we don't support arrays in properties.**

Please follow [Azure Digital Twins updates, blogs, and announcements](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/digital-twins/#updates-announcements) to get latest information on upcoming features. Also [Product Updates page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?product=digital-twins&category=iot&query=Azure%20Digital%20Twins).